# How can I set permissions for S3 bucket to be accessed by a specific group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

this is what I have:

```
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1381504474400",
      "Action": [
        "s3:CreateBucket",
        "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::awesome-bucket/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

and it says its missing the "principal" element....
how can I add a group to that? what is the syntax???